# node.js express - handling routes as app.get('route', folder.file)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I have seen this format in a couple of tutorials, but im new to node.js and in the courses I made they taught me to write routes as:

```
app.get('/example', function(request, response){});
```

instead, I have seen many using it like:

```
app.get('/example', routes.example);
```

having then a folder "routes" with a file inside "example.js"

Can someone maybe give me a little explanation to this way of handling routes, why is it better and what are the difference using it like that in terms of implementation?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary difference is where the logic for the route is defined. The latter of the two choices is usually encouraged because it decouples the responsibility of the routes and makes the code a little cleaner to read.

`app.get('/example', function(req, res) {});`

In the above route definition, the logic for that route is defined inside the function that gets called when a request is made against `/example`. When you have many routes defined like this in a single file, it becomes difficult to follow and read.

`app.get('/example', routes.example);`

This route definition is more or less identical to the previous one in how it functions. The main advantage is that its far more readable when you have many route definitions in a single file.

As for the `./routes` directory with multiple route files in it, this is because of [Router Middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.router). The primary benefit to this is, routes can be defined in separate files and then injected as middleware into the main application.

I'd recommend using [`express-generator`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-generator) to create a new Express app and go through the structure of the app and its directories. This is more or less the encouraged structure for how an Express app should be laid out. It also will illustrate how to use Router Middleware properly and you'll get a good feel of how routes get injected into your main Express app.

Comment: Excellent explanation! I didnt know about the router middleware. I will read the links you sent me. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

The only difference between the two is enforcing a separation of concerns.

Some developers like the keep all the code related to a specific route in a separate controller file and just reference it in your router file.

It allows you to quickly and easily pin point the source of a bug and also allows other developers to get a broad overview of your project.

Example: if i have a route `/foo` I could create a `fooController` that handles all the actions that that route would need.

Answer (score 1):

In the second way the Router middleware loads all the controllers defined in the routes path by convention. The code would be cleaner and less verbose using convention over configuration, but in terms of functionality,performance or other aspects I think there is no difference.